# Find the pointing of maximum velocity on a trajectory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

I understand the fact that we need to calculate the derivative of velocity with respect to time and equate it to 0 to find when $v$ is at max. In the following part of the solution, $v(t)$ has already been calculated and you're seeing its derivative. Everything's okay so far, however, why is it immediately self- evident that derivative equals to zero **if and only if** sin(ωt) = 0. Why can't the denominator satisfy the if it's also 0?

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{R\omega}{2}\frac{2\omega sin(\omega t)}{\sqrt{2-2cos(\omega t)}}=0$$
$$ \iff sin(\omega t) = 0$$

Can it be because we're calculating the max. $v$ in y component or something along those lines?

Comment: It's basically *optimum theory* in Calculus: at a minimum/optimum the gradient (1st derivative) becomes zero.

Comment: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=2#pid442469 from a webinar of mine.

Comment: @Gert I agree on the fact that it should be zero why it is zero but why can it not be zero also when the denominator zero.

Comment: $\frac{a}{0}=\infty$!

Comment: It is not "immediately self evident" (nor true in this case). There is a complication here in that when the numerator (sin) is zero so too can the denominator be zero (1 - cos). In fact, sin(wt) does *not* imply dv/dt=0 in all cases. Rewrite the acceleration in terms of sin and expand around sin=0 and you will see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator being zero doesn't imply the total result is 0, dividing by zero is undefined, and dividing by an arbitarily small $\sqrt{2-2cos(\omega t)}$ will result in an arbitarily high result.

Comment: Makes sense, wanted to be sure of this, thank you.

Comment: An arbitrarily small (2 - 2cos) implies, in many cases, an arbitrarily small sin. For example, when sin goes to zero so too does (2 - 2cos). So the fraction in these case will not have an arbitrarily high value.

Comment: Since sine is odd around zero angle, while cosine is even, the derivative changes sign at zero angle.